# Opensips suddenly crash in two-three days running

Tags: voip, sip-server, opensips

I am using opensips, it is working fine but after 2-3 days it suddenly crash. Don't understand following log

```
CRITICAL:core:receive_fd: EOF on 17
INFO:core:handle_sigs: child process 14090 exited by a signal 11
INFO:core:handle_sigs: core was generated
 INFO:core:handle_sigs: terminating due to SIGCHLD
CRITICAL:core:receive_fd: EOF on 17
INFO:core:handle_sigs: child process 14090 exited by a signal 11
INFO:core:handle_sigs: core was generated
INFO:core:handle_sigs: terminating due to SIGCHLD
INFO:core:sig_usr: signal 15 received
```

How can I investigate what is exactly going wrong with my opensips. I am using Ubuntu, should I change it to Centos or Debian? or what above log dictate error? any idea.

Answer (score 1):

The log isn't telling you anything other than that it's crashed. The question is why.

If you run the same version & config on a different environment you'll probably have the same issues.

The time dependence of the crashes would suggest it's crashing when a specific race condition is met. This could be a call coming in with an invalid Caller ID you're trying to parse as an int, a routing block that's seldom called being called, a resource limitation on the system, or something totally different.

This is a pretty generic crash message, so without more debugging it's just guesswork, so let's enable debugging:

The start of the [OpenSIPs config file](https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips/blob/master/etc/opensips.cfg) is where we enable, here's how the default config looks (assuming you've built off the standard template):

```
####### Global Parameters #########

log_level=3
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

children=4

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug_mode=yes
```

If you change yours to:

```
####### Global Parameters #########

log_level=8
log_stderror=yes
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

children=4

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
debug_mode=yes
```

You'll have debugging features enabled and a whole lot more info available in syslog.

Once you've done that sit back and wait for 2 days until it crashes, and you'll have an answer as to what module / routing block / packet is causing your instance to crash.

After that you can post the output here along with your config file, but there's a pretty high chance that someone on the OpenSIPs or Kamailio mailing lists will have had the same issue before.